# Why are modern browser JS engines multi-threaded?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, internals

I understand modern browsers' JS engnines (like V8, Spidermonkey, Chakra, etc.) use thread pools internally, even though only a single thread (running the event loop) is exposed to a JS programmer.

Obviously, the (rarely used) Web Workers require multiple threads (or multiple processes) - otherwise they couldn't utilize multiple CPU cores. My question is, *apart* from Web Workers, what is the benefit of implementing JS engine with multiple threads?

Why couldn't JS engine remain always single-threaded by internally relying on the same event-loop that the JS programmers use, using non-blocking OS calls whenever it needs to do any IO?

To clarify: JS engine uses a thread pool even if the user opened just one window with just one tab.

Edit: this is answered [here](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-Google-V8-engine-work/answer/Sylvain-Genev%C3%A8s?srid=putc)

Comment: A browser is viewing multiple web pages at the same time?

Comment: @EdHeal I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @max Even with only one tab, the browser UI may also use JS in another process.

Comment: @Oriol What do you mean by "use JS in another process"? I was asking about JS Engine itself, which is not written in JavaScript. The only JS code executed by the browser is the script inlined in, or loaded by, the HTML page. All that code runs in a single thread, with the exception of special support for parallel execution such as Web Workers.

Comment: Well I don't know how JS engines work but the script in the HTML page may not be the only JS code running in the browser. The browser UI can be written in HTML and JS too.

Comment: The page runs in a single thread, but web workers each have their own thread.

Comment: @Amy even without web workers, and with a single window/tab, JS Engine itself uses multiple threads (even though as you say the programmer writing the script only has access to a single thread).

Comment: a possible use case is running GC on different thread

Comment: @BryanChen Yup. I just searched for that, and found [this explanation](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-Google-V8-engine-work/answer/Sylvain-Genev%C3%A8s?srid=putc) which confirms what you said - and also answers my question in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many parts of a script engine that benefit from parallelisation, as they can run concurrently for different parts of the script or in relation to each other:

- parsing
- compilation
- JIT, optimisation
- debugging/logging/profiling
- garbage collection
- graphics

And that doesn't even involve sharing between multiple instances of the engine for different usage environments (worker scripts, browsing contexts).

Comment: Is the IO completely single threaded, or it also benefits from multiple threads?

Comment: That depends a lot on the particular type of IO, and doesn't necessarily correspond to benefits for the js engine itself. Networking is typically done using non-blocking OS calls, while parallel file IO often needs threads. And then there's communication with other components of the browser such as the DOMs or the rendering pipeline, which are implemented in a multithreaded design as well.